# How to pass value from a cell to a textbox in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using this code but it does not work.

```
UserForm2.txtEcpNum.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value
```

Comment: What specifically "does not work"? Have you debugged and stepped through the code to see what values you get on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
UserForm2.txtEcpNum.Text = CStr(Range("B2").Value) 
UserForm2.Show
```

Simply replacing `UserForm2.txtEcpNum.Value` with `UserForm2.txtEcpNum.Text` may work also, but I'm not 100% sure